# Padding arround textview with nine patch background have no visual effect

Tags: android, textview, nine-patch

Im trying to create toast like control based on textview, and i found very strange behavior of textview in case when it have nine patch drawable as background.

This is xml definition:

```
<by.pplware.view.QuickInfo
    android:id="@+id/quickinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="20px"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:background="#FFFF0000"
/>
```

this is textview with color background:
[image]

this is textview with drawable background :
[image]

As i understand, in case of ninepatch background android make padding transparent and use drawable only as background for text. But I want to include padding into area covered with ninepatch background.

Is there any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try any of these:

1. Set the background ninepatch via the "android:background" xml property instead of programatically; this cooperates with XML-defined padding.
2. If you need to set the background programatically, try to re-set the padding after setting the background (if you set the padding then set the background, I'd assume the padding defined in the ninepatch itself overrides it).
3. Avoid the entire issue and just set the padding areas in your [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) image itself (that's the right and bottom black bars).

Comment: Thanks for coments - 1 and 2 realy helps.

Comment: I worked around this by saving the padding values before setting the nine patch and then reset padding as per 2 above.